# How do I make NetworkManager allow simultaneous openvpn tap connections

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, networkmanager

I have several openvpn connections imported to NetworkManager from .ovpn files.

For example, different connections for several cloud service regions.

But, when I use NetworkManager to connect to new vpn connection, it disconnects previous one.

And NetworkManager always use device name tap0.

I haven't found where in NetworkManager`s settings I can force it to use different device names for different tap vpn connections.

That's gross. How do I make NetworkManager connect several tap vpns simultaneously?

Your help is appreciated.

> Package: network-manager
> Version: 0.9.10.0-7
>
> Package: network-manager-openvpn
> Version: 0.9.10.0-1

Answer (score 1):

[Upgrade](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/NEWS#n132) to NetworkManager 1.2 or later (and accordingly update networkmanager-openvpn).

```
============================================
NetworkManager-1.2
Overview of changes since NetworkManager-1.0
============================================

This is a new stable release of NetworkManager.  Notable changes include:

...
* The API for VPN plugins now supports multiple simultaneous connections.
    Most popular VPN plugins have been updated to support this functionality.
```

Alternatively, start your OpenVPN connections *directly* (e.g. via `openvpn@foo.service`), without any NM involvement.